# ObservableCollection memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks, observablecollection

I use MVVM light in my application.
I don't know how i can release the memory of an ObservableCollection Here is my ViewModel :

```
    ObservableCollection<string> collTest = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public VMTest()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
            collTest.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}", x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x));
    }

    public ICommand DeleteColl { get { return new RelayCommand(DeleteCollExecute, CanDeleteCollExecute); } }
    bool CanDeleteCollExecute() { return true; }
    void DeleteCollExecute()
    {
        collTest.Clear();
    }
```

The view :

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click"
                    Name="bt_test"
                    Content="New VMTest" />
            <Button Content="delete ObservableCollection"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteColl}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

The code Behind :

```
    public TestMemoryLeak()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new VMTest();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new VMTest();
    }
```

When i click on "bt_test" it will create a new viewModel for my view. i've got an other button to clear the observableCollection.

If i assign a new viewModel or if i clear the ObsevableCollection, the memory is never release.
For this example, it take 15Mo more every click on "bt_test" .  On my application, it take 50 mega each time, i arrived to reach 1.4Go of consumption in a test ... (i stopped the test)

Can you help me ?

EDIT :

After investigation, it seems it is my DAO the guilty, is it possible it is when i copy the ObervableCollection the problem ?

```
LocColl = new ObservableCollection<Localite>(Factory.getILocalite().ListLocalite());
```

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: i used the VS2013 analyser and my old TaskManager :-)

Comment: TaskManager is not a good tool for measuring memory.  Let the loop run 10000 times and see if you get and actual OOM exception.

Comment: @Blam is right.  Allocating memory is expensive, so the CLR holds onto as much memory it needs until it has to let it go.  Unless your application get an OOM as he says, there is no problem.

Comment: Will it be released after the garbage collector has been run

Comment: @eFloh Released and measured are not the same.  Task Manager is not a good tool for measuring memory.  If it truly is a memory leak then no it would not be released.

Comment: @Blam: you are totaly right, I just wanted to add the bit that _without_ the GC collection, the memory will for sure still be in use (without any implications what that means to measured or now (re-)usable memory

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micmcd/archive/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic.aspx) article I read that WPC checks to find things that implement INotifyPropertyChanged. So to fix this memory leaks you just need to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** ind your ViewModel also if your don't need the PropertyChanged event.

Give it a try. Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot this : My ViewModel implement ObservableObject wich implement INotifyPropertyChanged